# afterEach top-level describe

Tags: mocha.js

Each one of my files has all of it's tests wrapped in a `describe`. I want to run an async function after each one of these top-level describe blocks.

I put an `afterEach` but it's running after every one of my `it` blocks. Is there anyway to make it go after the top-level `describe` blocks?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the 'after' hook. Take a look at https://mochajs.org/#hooks.

Comment: Thanks @MuratK but I have to do this in every one of my many test files, i was hoping there was a global short cut to do `after` for every top-level describe. I currently have pasted the same thing in all the `after`s but its so repetitive.